# Which is better: a dimension or a macro?

Tags: macros, tex-core, programming, lengths

When messing around with TikZ/PGF then I frequently find myself wanting to store a length for later use.  By "length" here, I mean the word in its non-TeX meaning.  As I'm doing stuff in TikZ/PGF then I tend to use `\pgfmath` for the later processing so it doesn't matter *for usage* whether I store that length as a TeX-length or as a macro (providing I remember which I've done!).

So which is the better option?

The considerations that occur to me are: number of registers of each type, speed of look-up, speed of parsing, robustness of code (I feel that for a *Cargo Cult Programmer* such as myself then `\edef\savedlength{\oldlength}` or `\let\savedlength=\oldlength` is safer than `\savedlength=\oldlength` when `\oldlength` might not itself be a TeX-length).  But I'm sure that there are others that I haven't thought of (being a humble CCP!).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For normal LaTeX usage and few lengths in points or other fixed unit I would recommend the usage of dimension registers (LaTeX: *length*, TeX: `\dimen`). Their benefit is that they are faster, already terminated and can be prefixed with a factor. The drawback is that you need to allocate the register and must be careful not to use it on its own inside a text.

For `pgfmath` the benefit of the scale factor disappears almost completely because it allows you to use use `*` for multiplication.

One benefit for macros is that they can hold length with `em` or `ex` unit which are font size specific. If you assign such values to a length register they are converted to `pt` at the moment of assignment and not when they are used.

If you use mostly `pgfmath` expressions and need several lengths incl. font size specific ones, I would stick to macros. You will need to remember if you dealing with lengths registers or macros in several cases anyway, so it would be better to stick with one thing. `\dimexpr` makes this also a little simpler if you need a dimension expression.

With eTeX there is also the possibility to define *pseudo-lengths* using `\dimexpr`. You can e.g. say `\def\mylength{\dimexpr 1em\relax}` and use it like a length register, i.e. you can use a factor in front of it and can (and must) use `\the` to get the string representation. Note that `pgfmath` handles lengths register by detecting its type but [can't handle `\dimexpr`](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3165954&group_id=142562&atid=752792) yet. So `\mylength` will be expanded first and the `\dimexpr` will break. To use them in `pgfmath` expressions you need to convert it to a string using `\the` first. 
This is one thing which stops you from using `\pgfmathsetlength` as a drop-in replacement of `\setlength` for existing code.

Comment: on the handling of `\dimexpr` in `pgfmath`: one possible approach would be to automatically insert `*\the` before any non-expandable control sequence (except `\relax`, I guess). This takes care of multiplication and unpacking. Of course, it breaks if the user puts a non-expandable non-register primitive in the expression. Is that an issue?

Comment: @Bruno: IIRC the PGF code at this position was quite tricky and I couldn't hack it without studying it further. Inserting a `\the` or anything else might be not possible due to the way the expression is processed. But I'm not fully sure.

Comment: I don't know PGF well. But does it seem like a good approach in principle? I'm coding an expandable version of \pgfmathparse now, and that's my current plan.

Answer (score 19):

In general, I would favour using TeX dimen registers for storing fixed lengths. In general, TeX is faster parsing these than the equivalent data stored in a macro. This is because registers are properly 'terminated' as far as TeX is concerned: this shows up more with other data types than for fixed lengths.

What you do need to watch is that

```
\let\savedlength=\oldlength
```

is fine when `\oldlength` is a macro, but when `\oldlength` is a dimen you are copying not the *content* but the pointer to a register:

```
\newdimen\mydimena
\newdimen\mydimenb
\mydimena 10 pt
\let\mydimenb\mydimena
\mydimena 20 pt
\showthe\mydimenb
```

I would use something like

```
\newdimen\savedlength
\savedlength\oldlength\relax
```

which will perform an assignment to set `\savedlength` to the value of `\oldlength`, and is safe whether `\oldlength` is a macro or a dimen. If e-TeX is available, I'd also use `\dimexpr` to avoid leaving any `\relax` tokens spare:

```
\savedlength\dimexpr\oldlength\relax
```

(This works because `\dimexpr` is terminated by a `\relax` which it will remove. So here the `\relax` will disappear to leave an  whether `\oldlength` is a macro or a dimen.)