# Why does \dimexpr swallow \relax?

Tags: expansion, e-tex, dimension-expressions

Following the comments at [Doing maths with distance values in LaTeX source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/doing-maths-with-distance-values-in-latex-source-code/11347#11347):

> +1 for teaching me that `\dimexpr` can optionally swallow a `\relax`. Yesterday I tried to use `\relax` as a delimiter for `\numexpr`, and I just couldn't understand why the `\relax` is gone although it's not expandable. – Hendrik Vogt Feb 18 at 9:32
>
> @Hendrik: Yeah, I think you need two `\relax` then. I find the `\relax` swallowing extremely useful. Its friends like `\numexpr` do the same. – Martin Scharrer♦ Feb 18 at 9:36

and with this issue being touched on again by the answers of Joseph and Martin at [Which is better: a dimension or a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/which-is-better-a-dimension-or-a-macro), I ask myself why does Etex do things this way?  I find it unintuitive and I don't see how it can be useful to avoid carrying out a no-operation command.

Comment: Well, one alternative would be something like TeX' "keep on expanding until you find something you don't expect" semantics when parsing values, which is ... well, it's intuitive once you've gotten used to it. ;)

Comment: (I just left this as a comment on the original, but it could do with being here as well) Can we clarify that "optionally" in the first quoted sentence?  Is it really optional?

Comment: @Andrew: `\dimexpr`, _etc._ are terminated by the first token which cannot form part of an appropriate number. So something like a letter will terminate `\numexpr` without needing a `\relax`. So it is optional.

Comment: @Joseph: It wasn't whether the `\relax` is optional but whether the **swallowing** was optional.

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, I see. In that case, it should perhaps read 'swallowing an optional `\relax`', as the swallowing itself is not optional.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To add to what Hendrik says, I think the overall point was that `\numexpr`, `\dimexpr`, *etc.* can be used in a full expansion context without leaving a stray `\relax` or space:

```
\edef\example{\the\dimexpr 10 pt + 20 pt \relax}
```

gives `\example` defined as `30pt` with no unexpected tokens. That is in many ways much 'neater' than the alternative of leaving the `\relax` in place. The same argument does not apply to TeX's setting of registers as that is never expandable, so the issue does not arise.

(Of course, for a definitive answer you would need to ask the members of the NTS team who actually wrote this code.)

Comment: IIRC, that was indeed one of the main reasons for doing it this way.

Comment: It's the "much 'neater'" that I am having difficulties with.  The expected semantics of \relax is to have a do nothing token survive the expansion process to be looked at and discarded by the backend.  Etex would be faithful to *this* intuition if it took the \relax token from the input stream, did its work, and then put the token back.  Then, for instance, a very experienced TeXnician like Hendrik would not have got into difficulty.  How is this not neater?

Comment: @Charles: 'Neater' is of course subjective. To me, it's neater that `\example` ends up as a length *and nothing else*, so I can compare a number I type in with one that is calculated (using two macros and `\ifx`). `\relax` is not itself part of the number, so to me should be 'tided up' inside an `\edef`. As I say, this is a subjective thing, and I certainly had nothing to do with writing e-TeX.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I understand what you mean; perhaps it would have been neater to have these expressions be (optionally) terminated by a different token like `\endexpr` instead of reusing `\relax`; that way we'd have the best of both worlds: the `\edef` in this answer (with `\endexpr` in place of `\relax`) would still work, and if you really wanted `\relax` for some reason then that would remain too. But IMO the current solution is fine, and one can just adopt a habit of always ending a `\dimexpr` with `\relax`. (So if you do want a `\relax` that stays, you just have two `\relax`.)

Answer (score 11):

I would say this makes it easy to delimit a `\dimexpr` in a fully expandable way. Putting a `\relax` is a usual way to delimit TeX dimensions, [which I learned the hard way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8393/how-do-lastskip-and-ifdim-work): It's always a good idea to put a `\relax` after something like `\hskip1pt`. Now it seems that eTeX just made a principle out of this.

(An alternative is to put a *space* to delimit a TeX dimension, but firstly a `\relax` is a lot more visible, and secondly it's sometimes not so easy to put a space, namely after a control sequence. As Bruno points out in his comment, spaces *cannot* be used to delimit `\dimexpr` and friends.)

Comment: A space delimits a dimension, but cannot stop `\dimexpr`. One somewhat surprising case is `\the\numexpr 1+2 3+4`, which expands to `33+4`: the number `2` is stopped by a space, and the `3` does not fit at that place in the `\numexpr`, which is thus stopped. A similar example can probably be built for `\dimexpr`.

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks a lot for pointing this out! Is it better with my edit?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 8):

For the same reason as TeX gobbles a trailing spaces from numbers. In the case of TeX, this is needed to stop a number cleanly and make sure that in all cases it will be terminated without expanding anything further nor inserting a blank space. In fact, TeX probably skips spaces after control words (multiletter control sequences) for the same reason (although that happens at a different stage of processing). The idea is that it should always be possible to "stop without inserting anything".

Example: `\ifdigit` below tests whether the argument is a digit. The space after `#1` is required to stop TeX from expanding the first `\expandafter` prematurely. On the other hand, we don't want the space to end up in the output. So in that case at least, TeX's space gobbling is a feature.

```
\long\def\ifdigit#1{%
    \ifnum 9<1\string #1 %
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi}
```

eTeX's designers could decide that a space stops the `\numexpr` or `\dimexpr`, because they simply use TeX's procedures to read operands. And these procedures already remove a trailing space. eTeX does not see the space before `+` in `\numexpr 1 + 2`. It would have been technically possible to let `\numexpr` be stopped by *two* space tokens in a row, and gobble them, but that would be very difficult to input, since two space characters in a row are equivalent to one. Some other delimiter had to be chosen. It had to be non-expandable, preferably already there in the language, and it had better do nothing when used outside a `\...expr` situation... No need to add a new primitive: `\relax` was a natural choice.

Now consider a `\compareint` function defined as follows

```
\long\def\compareint#1#2#3{%
    \ifnum\numexpr#1\relax#2\numexpr#3\relax
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi}
\compareint{1+2}<{3-1}{Yes}{No}
```

In this particular case, leaving `\relax` behind would not be a problem. However, think of nesting this:

```
\def\X{345}\def\Y{534}
\compareint {132} < {\compareint{12}>{9}{\X}{\Y}+1} {Yes} {No}
```

If the `\relax` was not removed from the internal `\compareint`, it would stop expansion of the outside `\compareint` too early (actually, before expanding to `\X` or `\Y`, so that would be a problem).

Comment: In `\compareint`, you can miss out the first `\relax` as `#1` *will* be terminated by the comparator `#2`.

Comment: @Joseph: that's true. I hesitated when posting, but I think that putting `\relax` makes slightly clearer the fact that `#2` is the comparison character. It also provides somewhat better error checking (against input like `\compareint{1+2}{3}...` where the user forgets the comparison). I should have said that this is taken directly from `l3int` (which doesn't have the first `\relax`).

Comment: I know the relax is not in `l3int`, that's why I commented :-)

Comment: @Joseph. I just did some speed comparison. On 10000000 `\int_compare:nNnTF`, I get 116 seconds both with and without the first `\relax`. So we may want to put it in `l3int`. I think the reason why it makes no speed difference is that in both cases two tokens are read. With `\relax`, `\relax` is read and swallowed, and then the comparison character, and without, the comparison character is seen, put back, and re-read.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the single paragraph of [documentation in the e-TeX manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/etex_man.pdf#page=8) already answers this question with an illustrative example, which surprisingly has not been mentioned in the answers here. The example given there is:

```
\ifdim\dimexpr (2pt-5pt)*\numexpr 3-3*13/5\relax + 34pt/2<\wd20
```

as equivalent to `\ifdim 32pt < \wd20`. In this case, the inner `\numexpr 3-3*13/5\relax` expands to `-5` (note rounding), so that the outer `\dimexpr` becomes equivalent to `(-3pt) * (-5) + 17pt`. If the `\relax` were not swallowed, and were instead left on the input stream, then the outer `\dimexpr` would also get terminated at the `\relax`, resulting in errors.

---

For completeness, reproducing the [documentation of the grammar](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/etex_man.pdf#page=8) here, lightly reformatted:

> e-TeX introduces the notion of expressions of type number, dimen, glue, or muglue, that can be used whenever a quantity of that type is needed. Such expressions are evaluated by e-TeX’s scanning mechanism;
>
> - they are **initiated** by one of the commands `\numexpr`, `\dimexpr`, `\glueexpr`, or `\muexpr` (determining the type *t*) and optionally **terminated** by one **`\relax` (that will be absorbed by the scanning mechanism)**.
> - An **expression**: consists of one or more terms of the same type to be added or subtracted;
> - a **term** of type *t*: consists of a **factor** of that type, optionally multiplied and/or divided by **numeric factors**; finally
> - a **factor** of type *t*: is either a parenthesized subexpression or a quantity (number, etc.) of that type.
>
> Thus, the conditional
>
> ```
> \ifdim\dimexpr (2pt-5pt)*\numexpr 3-3*13/5\relax + 34pt/2<\wd20
> ```
>
> is true if and only if the width of box 20 exceeds `32 pt` .
>
> Note the use of `\relax` to terminate the inner (numeric) expression, the outer (dimen) expression is terminated automatically by the token `<`₁₂ that does not fit into the expression syntax.

And then there are a couple more paragraphs about arithmetic (e.g. rounding), and how this is expandable.