# How to scale a scheme in chemfig, using the figure environment

Tags: scaling, chemfig

I am trying to scale a reaction scheme generated with `chemfig` to `.9/textwidth`. Below is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[width=.9\textwidth]
\schemestart
\ce{O2^.-}\arrow (c1--c2){0}\ce{NO^.}\merge{v}(c1)(c2)--(c3)\ce{ONOO-}
\arrow (--c4){<=>[*{0}\parbox{1.2cm}{\ce{+ H+}\\ pK 6.6}][*{0}\ce{- H+}]}[-90,1.5]\ce{ONOOH}
\arrow(--c5){->[\ce{+ NO^.}][\ce{- HNO2}]}[0,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
\arrow(--c6){->[\ce{+ NO^.}]}\ce{N2O3}
\arrow(@c4--c7){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}][\ce{- OH-},\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
\arrow(@c7--c8){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}]}[180]\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering \ce{O2NOO-}\\or \\\ce{NO2- + O2}}
\arrow(@c3--@c7){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.}]}[2.12]
\arrow(@c3--@c5){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.-}]}[2.12]
\arrow(@c1--c9){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}, \ce{+ 2H+}][\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{H2O2}
\arrow(@c9--c10){->[\ce{Fe2+}][\ce{- OH-}]}[180]\ce{^.OH}
\arrow(@c2--c11){->[\ce{+ O2}]}$[$\ce{^.ONOO}$]$
\arrow(@c11--c12){->[\ce{+ ^.NO}]}\ce{2 NO2^.}
\schemestop

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, this still results in the following and seems not to scale the figure:

```
Overfull \hbox (71.11223pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 20--21.
```

Any thoughts and comments how to change this would be very much appreciated. Hope that is clear enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put it in a `\scalebox` perhaps:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[width=.9\textwidth]
\scalebox{.6}{
\schemestart
\ce{O2^.-}\arrow (c1--c2){0}\ce{NO^.}\merge{v}(c1)(c2)--(c3)\ce{ONOO-}
\arrow (--c4){<=>[*{0}\parbox{1.2cm}{\ce{+ H+}\\ pK 6.6}][*{0}\ce{- H+}]}[-90,1.5]\ce{ONOOH}
\arrow(--c5){->[\ce{+ NO^.}][\ce{- HNO2}]}[0,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
\arrow(--c6){->[\ce{+ NO^.}]}\ce{N2O3}
\arrow(@c4--c7){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}][\ce{- OH-},\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
\arrow(@c7--c8){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}]}[180]\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering \ce{O2NOO-}\\or \\\ce{NO2- + O2}}
\arrow(@c3--@c7){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.}]}[2.12]
\arrow(@c3--@c5){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.-}]}[2.12]
\arrow(@c1--c9){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}, \ce{+ 2H+}][\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{H2O2}
\arrow(@c9--c10){->[\ce{Fe2+}][\ce{- OH-}]}[180]\ce{^.OH}
\arrow(@c2--c11){->[\ce{+ O2}]}$[$\ce{^.ONOO}$]$
\arrow(@c11--c12){->[\ce{+ ^.NO}]}\ce{2 NO2^.}
\schemestop
}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, to answer the more specific question of matching the figure width to the textwidth, we can borrow from Philipp's answer at [How to find the ratio of a length command (e.g., \textwidth) to a reference value (e.g., 6cm) ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/how-to-find-the-ratio-of-a-length-command-e-g-textwidth-to-a-reference-valu), and can indirectly scale the box to the textwidth as follows (note I add a lipsum paragraph to show it is the proper width).  To do this, I save the figure in `\x`.  Then I find the natural width of `\x`, so that I can develop the proper scale ratio.  Then I `\scalebox` the image to the proper scale:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DivideLengths}[2]{%
    \strip@pt\dimexpr\number\numexpr\number\dimexpr#1%
     \relax*65536/\number\dimexpr#2\relax\relax sp\relax
}
\makeatother
\global\newlength\thewidth
\newcommand\findwidth[1]{\setbox0\hbox{#1}\setlength\thewidth{\wd0}}
\begin{document}
\def\x{
\schemestart
\ce{O2^.-}\arrow (c1--c2){0}\ce{NO^.}\merge{v}(c1)(c2)--(c3)\ce{ONOO-}
\arrow (--c4){<=>[*{0}\parbox{1.2cm}{\ce{+ H+}\\ pK 6.6}][*{0}\ce{- H+}]}[-90,1.5]\ce{ONOOH}
\arrow(--c5){->[\ce{+ NO^.}][\ce{- HNO2}]}[0,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
\arrow(--c6){->[\ce{+ NO^.}]}\ce{N2O3}
\arrow(@c4--c7){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}][\ce{- OH-},\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
\arrow(@c7--c8){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}]}[180]\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering \ce{O2NOO-}\\or \\\ce{NO2- + O2}}
\arrow(@c3--@c7){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.}]}[2.12]
\arrow(@c3--@c5){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.-}]}[2.12]
\arrow(@c1--c9){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}, \ce{+ 2H+}][\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{H2O2}
\arrow(@c9--c10){->[\ce{Fe2+}][\ce{- OH-}]}[180]\ce{^.OH}
\arrow(@c2--c11){->[\ce{+ O2}]}$[$\ce{^.ONOO}$]$
\arrow(@c11--c12){->[\ce{+ ^.NO}]}\ce{2 NO2^.}
\schemestop
}
\findwidth{\x}
\begin{figure}[width=.9\textwidth]
\scalebox{\DivideLengths{\textwidth}{\thewidth}}{\x}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,
didn't know about `\scalebox`. Still new to all this. However it seems that this will not scale the figure to the `\textwidth`. Is there a way to scale it to the actual `\textwidth`?

Comment: @KatjaMenger Does the `\makebox` approach work for you?

Comment: It seems as if the `\makebox` only centers the figure, so that the overhang is on both sides and playing with fractions of `.9\textwidth` or `.8\textwidth` just shifts the figure more towards the left edge of the page.

Comment: @KatjaMenger, fixed, with the help of referenced page.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. I don't entirely understand what you did with the `\DivideLengths` command, but at least it now scales everything accordingly.

Comment: @KatjaMenger Someone asked Philipp that, too, but he did not have time to clarify.  Apparently, even the use of the `\relax` is quite esoteric in this context: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/why-does-dimexpr-swallow-relax

Comment: @KatjaMenger Just came across this question again and thought I'd mention for reference that `graphicx` also has a `\resizebox` command for scaling to a given size, so you could do `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{<scheme>}`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the easiest way out is not to scale the scheme but to slightly rearrange it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{showframe}% show page layout
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\schemestart
 \ce{O2^.-}\arrow (c1--c2){0}\ce{NO^.}
 \merge{v}(c1)(c2)--(c3)\ce{ONOO-}
 \arrow (--c4){<=>[*{0}\parbox{1.2cm}{\ce{+ H+}\\ pK 6.6}][*{0}\ce{- H+}]}[-90,1.5]\ce{ONOOH}
 \arrow(--c5){->[\ce{+ NO^.}][\ce{- HNO2}]}[0,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
 \arrow(--c6){->[*0\ce{+ NO^.}]}[-90]\ce{N2O3}
 \arrow(@c4--c7){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}][\ce{- OH-},\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
 \arrow(@c7--c8){->[*0\ce{+ O2^.-}]}[-90]\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering \ce{O2NOO-}\\or \\\ce{NO2- + O2}}
 \arrow(@c3--@c7){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.}]}[2.12]
 \arrow(@c3--@c5){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.-}]}[2.12]
 \arrow(@c1--c9){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}, \ce{+ 2H+}][\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{H2O2}
 \arrow(@c9--c10){->[*0\ce{Fe2+}][*0\ce{- OH-}]}[-90]\ce{^.OH}
 \arrow(@c2--c11){->[\ce{+ O2}]}$[$\ce{^.ONOO}$]$
 \arrow(@c11--c12){->[*0\ce{+ ^.NO}]}[-90]\ce{2 NO2^.}
\schemestop
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @KatjaMenger whatever suits you best! :) I find it strange though that you're required layout - the adjustments does not change any meaning or information (I actually think there's a slight gain in information by having the products aligned horizontally). (Don't forget to vote on any answer you found useful such as Steven's).

Comment: “that you're required layout” should read “that you're required to use a certain layout/arrangement”

Comment: @StevenSegletes Unfortunately I am not able to vote yet. I will as soon as I can. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The optional argument to the `figure` environment only deals with the allowed position of the float, it cannot contain scaling or other things.

Another way of reducing the size is to simply reduce the fontsize, by adding `\scriptsize` right after `\begin{figure}`.

You can also squeeze things together a bit with the optional argument to `\schemestart`, e.g. `\schemestart[0,.7]`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\scriptsize
\schemestart
% option 2 -- comment out the two previous lines, uncomment the two next.
%\small
%\schemestart[0,.7]
\ce{O2^.-}\arrow (c1--c2){0}\ce{NO^.}\merge{v}(c1)(c2)--(c3)\ce{ONOO-}
\arrow (--c4){<=>[*{0}\parbox{1.2cm}{\ce{+ H+}\\ pK 6.6}][*{0}\ce{- H+}]}[-90,1.5]\ce{ONOOH}
\arrow(--c5){->[\ce{+ NO^.}][\ce{- HNO2}]}[0,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
\arrow(--c6){->[\ce{+ NO^.}]}\ce{N2O3}
\arrow(@c4--c7){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}][\ce{- OH-},\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{NO2^.}
\arrow(@c7--c8){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}]}[180]\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering \ce{O2NOO-}\\or \\\ce{NO2- + O2}}
\arrow(@c3--@c7){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.}]}[2.12]
\arrow(@c3--@c5){->[\ce{+ CO2}][\ce{- CO3^.-}]}[2.12]
\arrow(@c1--c9){->[\ce{+ O2^.-}, \ce{+ 2H+}][\ce{- O2}]}[180,1.5]\ce{H2O2}
\arrow(@c9--c10){->[\ce{Fe2+}][\ce{- OH-}]}[180]\ce{^.OH}
\arrow(@c2--c11){->[\ce{+ O2}]}$[$\ce{^.ONOO}$]$
\arrow(@c11--c12){->[\ce{+ ^.NO}]}\ce{2 NO2^.}
\schemestop

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```